# I'm making Swift framework but it doesn't have the class I made

Tags: swift, class, frameworks, instance

I'm testing creating framework.

[image]

So, I made the test framework first.
[image]

And in another project, I imported the framework but I can't access the `MyClass` I made.

What's the problem?  I don't know weather if can't access the class or framework doesn't have the class I made.

I'm struggling with this problem about two days.
Help me please.

Comment: Can you share the project with me? It will be easier to debug locally.

Comment: How can I share the project? But The project is all I posted. It's empty framework and project.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue.PFB the explanation.

- You have built the framework against '**Generic iOS device**'.
- You are trying to use against **simulator** which requires x86_64 architecture.

*This is the reason which your iOS framework classes are not getting recognized in your view controller. Since your framework is built only for iOS devices.*

**Solution to your Question:**

- Change your build target device to 'Generic iOS device' and just build it and you can't run.

**Generic Solution:**

- Try the tutorials for building universal framework where you will add 'Run Script phase' to create binary slices for all architectures(32-bit, 64-bit devices and simulators).

**Output:**
[image: Building Against iPhone5s simulator]
[image: Included Framework and build against wrong target][image: Correct Target][image: Embed the framework]

Comment: oh my god! I solved the problem. thank you very much Tesan!! I love you and thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad I can help you solving your problem. Please up vote and mark answered if you find my answer is correct.

Comment: OK. I tried up vote but I can't it. I have answered. have a good day!